# Chrome form reset don't change display select element

Tags: jquery, forms, google-chrome, select, microsoft-edge

When I reset the form the select element value reset but still display the old value

I'm using this to reset the form

```
$('#testForm')[0].reset();
```

In this example the 'Two' option is selected by default.
If I change the selection and press 'reset form' the select value change back but still shows the old value

in Edge its working

https://jsfiddle.net/z6vk91sL/

Google Chrome   83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)

```js
$('#testFormReset').on("click", () => {
  $('#testForm')[0].reset();
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='testForm'>
  <select>
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option selected value='2'>Two</option>
    <option value='3'>Three</option>
  </select>

  <button id='testFormReset' type='reset'>
    reset form
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: no, it stays as i changed. if i open the select again i see that the 'Two' is selected but the old value still shows in the input

Comment: I can confirm that when I select Three then click "reset form", it does not switch back to Two with Chrome v83.0.4103.61. It **does** switch back with Brave based on a slightly-older Chromium v81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit). So it sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into [issue #1087031](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1087031), which was reported five days ago and has been fixed. The fix will make its way out into release before too long, probably v84 (it's targeted at M-84).

I found the issue by searching for [select reset component:Blink>Forms](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=select%20reset%20component%3ABlink%3EForms&can=1) at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues.

Comment: Thank You , I'll make a temporary fix for the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are having this issue in the **Google Chrome** and **MS Edge browser** as both browsers use the same browser engine.

As the issue is already reported and fixed on the Chromium site.

Here I am sharing you the workaround that you can use temporarily.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="testForm">
  <select id="my_select">
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2' selected>Two</option>
    <option value='3'>Three</option>
  </select>

  <button id='testFormReset'>
    reset form
  </button>
</form>
<script>
$('#testFormReset').on("click", () => {
    $('#my_select option').prop('selected', function() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });

    $('#testForm')[0].reset();
 
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Output in the MS Edge(on the left side) and Google Chrome browser:

[image]

Comment: It works on the MS Edge legacy browser but you can see a similar issue with the MS Edge Chromium browser. The above workaround will work on both the MS Edge Chromium browser and the Google Chrome browser. Thanks for your understanding.